# Edit m4s files video

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, mp4box

In my application i'm saving my video files in M4S format.
I want to make an editing option for these files, my requirements are adding text and images at specific point of a video.

My first thought was to generate photo for text inserting (using [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)) which is very easy.

Now my goal is to make a single photo as a m4s file. preferably i would like to choose my own name for that file.

How can i achieve that?

The flow should be:

image.jpg -> 5.m4s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m4s` files do not contain the metadata that allow to play it (also called segment initialization) so they are not independent. 
You can try this:

1. Merge the `m4s` files to one `mp4` file.
2. Do simple [image overlay](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg) (with your text image) to step 1 output file.
3. Split again the output file of step 2 to `m4s` files.

Comment: how would you suggest splitting the mp4 file after merging it?

Comment: It is very depends on the video codec. `.mp4` is just the container that can include the audio, video, etc. For example, if the video codec is `H.264`, then you can use `X264` and `MP4Box` tools. See [here](https://bitmovin.com/mp4box-dash-content-generation-x264/) detailed instructions.